# 'jQuery' is undefined in while using bundle in mvc

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Step 1- We have merge 
            1) jquery-1.7.2.js,
            2) jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js,
            3) jquery.validate.js,
            4) jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
       In Single file using online js compressing tool. And saved that new file in our application script folder.

Step 2- When we are using new file in our application by using 
         " script src="Domain_Path"+"/Scripts/CDNScripts/jqueryval.js" type="text/javascript">"/script>
         Its working very good.

Step 3- **BUT** when we are **using bundling and CDN like below**. 
         bundles.UseCdn = false;
         string JqueryvalCND = "Domain_Path" + "/Scripts/CDNScripts/jqueryval.js";
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval", JqueryvalCND).Include(
                "~/Scripts/CDNScripts/jqueryval.js"));

```
    **It producing error "'jQuery' is undefined "**
```

Please suggest urgent

Comment: try changing the order of including bundles

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your bundle in your page too :

Razor : `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Web Forms : `<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") %>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. That I have already added like "@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")" in my _Layout(master page) page and this error still there, I think when we are using CDN then the file which we have included there that stores in its memory and when we are going to access that file its produce error. Please suggest what I do. Thanks

Comment: Render "@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")" at the place you have render other scritps. It will work.
My code start working now by above rendering 
Thanks